# Creating a sub collection in Firestore with swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to dynamically implement a subcollection of "attendees" to an event ID but struggling with implementing it, from what I can tell it should be possible I'm just struggling to figure out how, the documentation I've checked only shows hardcoded versions, but creating an "attendees" collection manually is not ideal

```
    // -MARK: Sign Up Btn
    @IBAction func signUpBtnTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // create firebase atendee add atendee to the ride attendee,
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let user = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)!
        let attend = "Attendees"
        //db.collection("Events").document(docID).collection("Attendees").addocument("userID")
        db.collection("Events").document(docID).collection(attend).addDocument(data: user)
    }
}
```

Here is what my current database looks like, 
[image: Image of current databse]

This is what the the goal is that I am going for
[image: Goal Implimentation]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What exactly is your goal ? (The pic is not showing clearly the final result you want, do you want a list of users with info and event ID ?). Please share code you've tried so far, documentation you tried to follow. The code you shared is simply a creation of a Document with a field and a value.

Comment: So i fixed the issue by creating another collection and storing the document Id and the id  . the goal was to create a sub collection for each event dynamically to store what is essentially a list of users and uid's as a list to act as someone attending an event